# mysqli database backup file save in folder

Tags: php, database, backup

I need to how to backup database and save backup file selected folder, using php

i'm try to use this one but it's not work...

```
$backupFile = $file . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.gz';
$command = "mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u testUser -p test123 testDb | gzip > $backupFile";
system($command);
```